# Where should the image "logo0.gif" be in order for this code to be able to use it?

Tags: java, swing, gif, imageicon

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    ImageIcon aLogo = new ImageIcon("Logo0.gif");
    JLabel aLabel = new JLabel(aLogo);
    JPanel aPanel = new JPanel();
    JFrame aFrame = new JFrame();
    aFrame.setSize(740, 320);
    aFrame.add(aPanel);
    aFrame.setVisible(true);
    aPanel.add(aLabel);
    aLabel.setIcon(aLogo);
}
```

Here i am trying to create a JFrame to display an image. However when i run this code there is no image on the JFrame, i believe that this is because of the file location.

Comment: Your code is assuming the image is in the same directory as the class file. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for a better way to read the image so that you can place the image anywhere on your classpath.

Comment: Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. This is basic Java coding conventions that can be found in any Java book or tutorial. Follow conventions if you expect people to take the time to read your code.

Comment: the image file is in the same directory as the class file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aFrame.setVisible(true);
aPanel.add(aLabel);
aLabel.setIcon(aLogo);
```

Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible, otherwise the layout manager is not invoked so the size of the component is (0, 0) which means there is nothing to paint.

Also, read the tutorial and download the demo code for a better way to structure your class so that the components are created properly on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Read the section from the above tutorial on `Concurrency in Swing` for more information about the EDT and why it is important.

Comment: i put "aFrame.setVisible(true); " after everything was added and it still didnt work. I copied the class file along with the image file and pasted them into an empty folder it the image was displaying, i dont understand why, but its working now, so problem solved i guess!